# How to make two distinct nodes same or opposite slope in CorelDraw and illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, bezier-curve

One of my recurrent problems in CorelDraw and Illustrator is that to make two distinct nodes looks exactly same as each other like mirror image. I know that one can draw in CorelDraw using symmetry option but my problem is a little technical. For example in the following

[image]

I want two nodes `C` and `D` to have same slope (i.e. control arrow of nodes have same slop) and two nodes `A` and `B` have opposite slope.

Is there a way to see the slope of control arrows of nodes? or there is a better and simple way for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not aware of any mechanism to "match" anchors in Illustrator. What you want *specifically* is not possible in Illustrator. As far as I'm aware, *nowhere* within Illustrator is there *any* display of slope information nor any angle information for Bezier handles.

Comment: Yes I am looking for a mechanism like "select two nodes and right click then choose 'set same slope'" or something similar that is easy to apply not like the answers given in below. :(  Your comment answers to my question. But I was hoping to hear that there is such a mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

I think if your goal is to make this look kind of symmetrical and not wonky, then it's not really the "slope" that you need to worry about, but rather the curves, and that the points you have marked A,B,C,D lie on and follow those curves consistently.

Start by creating a nice curve, something like this.

[image]

To that curve add a couple of extra anchors so that you can easily remove this segment later.

[image]

Reflect duplicates to create a whole wave shape

[image]

Select and delete the segments you don't need

[image]

Comment: Upvoted but not my desired answer.

Comment: @C.F.G Well, sometimes you have to consider different approaches, but thanks!

Comment: This, to me, seems like the only *feasible* option.

Comment: @Scott - a possible X-Y Problem, where the OP's "desired" method does not actually exist, and even if it did, wouldn't solve the problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously have already one of the curves, it must stay as is and the new curve must have exactly opposite endpoint handles. Otherwise the new curve can be different, maybe based on other requirements which you want to keep secret.

One good thing to know: In Illustrator you can draw  with the line tool a line segment which has the same direction and length as a handle. You can use such line as a jig to adjust the endpoint handle of a new curve.

Have snap to points and smart guides on. Activate the handles of an anchor by clicking the anchor with the direct selection tool. Draw the line by starting from the far end of the handle. The line start and end points snap and the line is not glued, you can use it later freely. An example:

[image]

In the top section the black lines are drawn along the handles.

In the middle section the handle visualization lines are moved to the assumed endpoints of the wanted new line. The original is moved aside temporarily to keep it in safe and the lines are locked to prevent gluing them to the red curve. The curve is drawn with the pen by simply dragging the pen along the handle lines.

Nothing prevents inserting more anchor points and even bringing the new curve from elsewhere. Convert the endpoints to corner points with the anchor type selection tool and then back to smooth ones by dragging the handles with the same tool. The tool snaps to the line end.

In the bottom section the original and the new curve are shown with handles.

Another good thing to remember: If you select a curve with the black arrow, hold the Ctrl key and drag one node of the curve, the whole curve follows and the dragged node snaps. Ctrl activates the white arrow temporarily.

Comment: Upvoted. just for sharing your idea. tnx